# Applying customized principal components to data in R

Tags: r, pca

I have applied `prcomp` function to get the principal components. I am currently using the first 3 principal components as variables. I am happy with the way the data is represented through them, so I decided to apply the same proceudure for another dataset. The problem is, if I do another `prcomp` for a new dataset, I am getting new combinations and therefore, new preincipal compoenets. Can I get the same principal components (with the same rotations/loadings) for the new data? This would be tedious to do manually (as I have hundreds of variables and tiny rotations) and I cannot seem to be able to think of a smart script to do that. Here's a reproducible example to resemble my data.

```
pca1 <- prcomp(USArrests, scale = TRUE)
pca1$rotation ##ideal Principal components
pca2 <- prcomp(iris[,1:4], scale = TRUE)
pca2$rotation ##not ideal
```

I would like to have principal components of the iris dataset, having the same rotations from variables as in the ISArrests dataset. Would that be possible?

Thanks,

Comment: “Can I get the same principal components (with the same rotations/loadings) for the new data?” No, because those aren’t the principal components of the other data. But you can just use the eigenvectors of the first PCA and multiply the second matrix with them (assuming the dimensions are compatible) to get the same rotation. Note, however, that this is **not** a PCA.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am aware this is not a PCA anymore, I just cannot think of how to actually get the Eigen vectors and do the multiplication. If you can show me how to do that I would be grateful :)

Comment: The eigenvectors are the columns of the `rotation` matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenvectors are the columns of the `rotation` matrix that `prcomp` returns.

In order to rotate another data matrix, you just need to multiply it with the rotation matrix, and optionally scale it beforehand.

In your case:

```
result = scale(iris[, 1:4]) %*% pca1$rotation
```

You can verify that this works using your original data:

```
pca1_should_be = scale(USArrests) %*% pca1$rotation
all.equal(pca1_should_be, pca1$x)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks! I was doing that the long way! the %*% was a smart move. Cheers.